# Use of certificates and keys in first-network example hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Cryptogen tool generates various keys and certificates in folder 'ordererOrganizations' and 'peerOrganizations'.
When browsed inside there are many other folders and certificates inside there. Can somebody briefly explains what is the purpose of each ?

```
- [error opening dir]
<p>- [error opening dir]<br />.<br />├── ordererOrganizations<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; └── example.com<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── 25cfd6658ce8f7f493e9712286965685332cda236ac0ec22944358e717277668_sk<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── orderers<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── orderer.example.com<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 7c6d86fdcbeec957f6c5984d0ad99a9696d90ea8791ba9d64c70ddc9f8d26f92_sk<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── orderer.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── tlsca<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── 194ffd9718bcdb465c4bebb56e227ca97b9dd34bcab3c8c00782295587e87012_sk<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; └── users<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@example.com<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── d3b4263f6c199507bb8122cbbba0424e57127635fc8a9219a3b0ec3078f320ac_sk<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br />│&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br />├─<br />└── peerOrganizations<br /> ├── org1.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── 4925e655394146c4f280ededd5d22a7f3f8df0a47e928948157ebf432836b14f_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── peers<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── peer0.org1.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 93bf5c084f717793207252286e90ba01067435a6c43879ad8063cca25281e933_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer0.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer1.org1.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 94e9c2936320266f0f16fb095a89c9b4fb199a000591153e08f3e4a9881c7e49_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer1.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── tlsca<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── bec014c38f2bc639f3798f346354fe521acba0018c7216bb4ea30b87334382c3_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── users<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── Admin@org1.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── f2b9f7c3207d1112819592e857074d4d4fa931c3d55705d7d13f052ce70b3955_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── User1@org1.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 1c3cb9181ef0cf6b45a1d4bc00cd5740f0fd1ce92b403b90da67ac42f8376847_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> └── org2.example.com<br /> ├── ca<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── 46cc6febd8eaf32fd01a1fef70e6ae4e27be40ce98b87b9abcc4669310ec92a7_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> ├── peers<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── peer0.org2.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ecbcb153faec9b55124ff64e731bf0f67012e3a519c342e533799dce3b6426d3_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer0.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer1.org2.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── a603431f3187d3cf06a538b0a587f473cc035b4d433a1b18b6e8a89ff3d4f56c_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── peer1.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> ├── tlsca<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── 11c1ea26783ddb559b31a5b60af563847a5316e75e5ef8b544f20cf072c44b43_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> └── users<br /> ├── Admin@org2.example.com<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 3a3da66dd78cc29ee7722e240caed43362ccf5522fdffd7ebeaa1a1066cb8c78_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tls<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── ca.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── server.crt<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── server.key<br /> └── User1@org2.example.com<br /> ├── msp<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── admincerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── cacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── keystore<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── 4e294d437896e2c1e93958a60615616c9ca7fd8f8b00482a16fa30abed28c2c4_sk<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── signcerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlscacerts<br /> │&nbsp;&nbsp; └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem<br /> └── tls<br /> ├── ca.crt<br /> ├── server.crt<br /> └── server.key</p>
<p>109 directories, 102 files</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This structure is used to establish the MSPs (membership service provider) that will be deployed to each orderer and peer node and is fully documented [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html).

To set up a local MSP (for either a peer or an orderer), the administrator should create a folder (e.g. $MY_PATH/mspconfig) that contains six subfolders:

- a folder admincerts to include PEM files each corresponding to an administrator certificate
- a folder cacerts to include PEM files each corresponding to a root CA’s certificate
- (optional) a folder intermediatecerts to include PEM files each corresponding to an intermediate CA’s certificate
- (optional) a folder crls to include the considered CRLs
  a folder keystore to include a PEM file with the node’s signing key; we emphasise that currently RSA keys are not supported
  a folder signcerts to include a PEM file with the node’s X.509 certificate
- (optional) a folder tlscacerts to include PEM files each corresponding to a TLS root CA’s certificate
- (optional) a folder tlsintermediatecerts to include PEM files each corresponding to an intermediate TLS CA’s certificate